# Solve $a^{2013}+b^{2013}=p^n$ for all positive integers a,b,n and prime numbers p

Tags: number-theory

Solve $a^{2013}+b^{2013}=p^n$ for all positive integers $a$, $b$, $n$ and prime numbers $p$.

I got that you can take $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and solve for it.

Comment: This is [EMC 2012 Senior Category, Problem 1](http://emc.mnm.hr/history)

Answer (score 2):

There are no solutions. Here is my proof.

The proof also shown that
if $3 | m$
and
$a^m+b^m = p^n$
then
$p=3$,
$a=1$ and $b=2$,
or
$3^n = 2^m+1$,
which has
no solutions other than
$m=3$ and $n=2$.

2013 factors as
3*11*61.

If $m$ is odd,
$a+b$
divides
$a^m+b^m
$.

Therefore,
if
$a^m+b^m = p^n$
where
$m = 2013$,
then
$a+b$
and
$a^3+b^3$
(and others)
divide $p^n$.

Therefore,
for some $u$ and $v$,
$a+b=p^u$
and
$a^3+b^3=p^v$.

Since
$a^3+b^3
=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)
$,
$a^2-ab+b^2
=p^{v-u}
$.

Also
$(a+b)^2
=a^2+2ab+b^2
=p^{2u}
$.
Therefore
$p^{2u}-p^{v-u}
=3ab
$
or
$3ab
=p^{2u}-p^{v-u}
=p^{v-u}(p^{3u-v}-1)
$.

If
$p | a$,
then
$p | b$,
which is not allowed
(since we want
$gcd(a, b) = 1$).
Therefore
$p | 3$,
so we must have $p = 3$.

Therefore
$v-u=1$
and
$ab 
= p^{3u-v}-1
= p^{2u+1}-1
$.

Since
$u \ge 1$,
$a^2-ab+b^2
=p^{v-u}
= p
\le p^u
= a+b
$.
Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
(a-b)^2
&=a^2-2ab+b^2\\
&=a^2-ab+b^2-ab\\
&\le a+b-ab\\
&=-(ab-a-b)\\
&=-(ab-a-b+1-1)\\
&=-((a-1)(b-1)-1)\\
&=-(a-1)(b-1)+1\\
\end{array}
$

Assume $a > b$
(if not, just swap them).

If $b \ge 2$,
then $a \ge 3$
so
$(a-b)^2
\le  -(a-1)(b-1)+1
\le -2+1
< 0
$
which is impossible.

If $b = 1$,
then
$(a-b)^2 = 1$
so $a = 2$.
Therefore
$u=1$ and $v = 2$.

These satisfy
$a+b = 3$
and
$a^3+b^3 =9 = 3^2$.

Looking at the
factorization of 2013
we must have
$a^{11}+b^{11} = p^m$
for some $m$
or
$3^m
=2^{11}+1
=2049
$,
which is not a power of 3.

Therefore,
there are no solutions.

(added later)

More generally,
we must have
$2^m+1 = 3^n
$
and this
has no solutions other that
$m=3$ and $n=2$.

Comment: Where did you exclude the solution $a=b=n=1$, $p=2$ ?

Comment: I didn't. That is a trivial solution.

Comment: Then your first sentence should be: "there are no *non-trivial* solutions".

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge 2$ we are in the hyperbolic case of Fermat's generalised equation, because then
$$
\frac{1}{2013}+\frac{1}{2013}+\frac{1}{n}<1
$$
Here we "believe" that there is no integral solution with exponent $2013$.

For $n=1$ we have the equation
$$
x^{2013}+y^{2013}=p
$$
for a prime $p$. The polynomial $f(x,y)$ on the LHS is not irreducible, since $x+y$ is a factor. So we cannot appeal to [Bunyakovsky conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture). (So we will not expect that infinitely many primes can be represented by $f$.). We have $x+y=p$, since $x$ and $y$ are prositive.
Then we have $x=y=1$, and $p=2$ (see the comments).

Comment: If $x+y$ is a factor of the prime $p$, then we can be sure that $x+y=p$. So $x=y=1$ is indeed the only solution when $n=1$.

Comment: If $x > 1$ or $y > 1$, then $p = x^{2013}+y^{2013}>x+y=p$.