# For fixed $m$, find all positive integer solutions to $a^m+b^m = p^n$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

The problem:

For fixed $m$, 
find all solutions to 
$a^m+b^m = p^n$ 
where $p$ is prime,
all variables are positive integers,
 $a \le b$,
and
$m \ge 2$.

This is a generalization 
of this question:
[Solve $a^{2013}+b^{2013}=p^n$ for all positive integers a,b,n and prime numbers p](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043900/solve-a2013b2013-pn-for-all-postiive-integers-a-b-n-and-prime-numbers)

My answer showed that
if $m$ is odd
and divisible by 3
then the only solution
(aside from the trivial one of
$a=b=1, p=2, n=1$)
is
$a=1, b=2, m=3, p=3, n=2$
(i.e.,
$1+8=9$).

I am now asking about
the solutions for
other values of $m$.

Some observations:

If $a = b$,
the equation is
$2a^m = p^n$,
so $p=2$,
$a=2^k$,
and
$n = km+1$.

If $m$ is even,
then $p^n$ is the
sum of two squares,
so the results there
can be used.
In particular, if $p$
is of the form
$4k+3$,
then $n$ must be even.

For what other classes of $m$,
or even particular values of $m$,
can all solutions be found?

Comment: See [Beal's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal's_conjecture).

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.

Comment: $n$ is a power of $p$ see :http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/q2h488214p2735645

Answer (score 1):

The only positive integer solutions of $p^n=a^m+b^m$ with $p$ prime, $m\ge 3$ not a power of $2$ are $(p,n,a,b,m)=(3,2,2,1,3),(2,km+1,2^k,2^k,m),\forall k\ge 1$.

If $a=b$, then $(p,n,a,b,m)=(2,km+1,2^k,2^k,m), k\ge 1$. If $(a,b,m)=(2,1,3)$, then $(p,n,a,b,m)=(3,2,2,1,3)$. Otherwise: let $m=2^kt$ with $t\ge 2$ odd. Then by [Zsigmondy's Theorem](https://www.math.ust.hk/excalibur/v16_n4.pdf):

$$a^m+b^m=\left(a^{2^k}+b^{2^k}\right)\left(a^{m-2^k}-a^{m-2^k-1}b\pm\cdots+b^{m-2^k}\right)$$

has a prime divisor that does not divide $a^{2^k}+b^{2^k}$, so $a^m+b^m$ has at least two different prime divisors.

---

However, this is not so simple if $m$ is a power of $2$. Some partial results:

If $m=2$, then $a^2+b^2=p^n$ has infinitely many positive integer solutions with $p$ prime. E.g., if $n=1$, then there exists a unique solution if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$; no solutions if $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$. See [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) (or Fermat's Christmas Theorem). Uniqueness isn't mentioned in the Wikipedia page, but it's easy to prove; see e.g. [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fermat's_Christmas_Theorem#Proof_of_Uniqueness) (there's a small mistake; it should be $(ad+bc)^2+(ac-bd)^2$).

If $m=2, n=2$, then $a^2+b^2=p^2$ has infinitely many positive integer solutions. It's well-known (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple)) that we must have $p=k(m^2+n^2)$ for some positive integers $k,m,n$ (wlog $m>n$). Clearly $k=1$. If we can find such $m,n$, then $\{a,b\}=\{2mn,m^2-n^2\}$ solves the equation. So $a^2+b^2=p^2$ is solvable iff $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

If $m=4$, in $1961$ it was unknown whether there are inifinitely many primes of the form $a^4+b^4$ (see [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.nmj/1118800590#ui-tabs-1)). If $m=2^t$ with $t\ge 2$, $n$ must be odd (see [here](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.lt/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-n-4.html)).

Also see [Generalized Fermat Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Generalized_Fermat_numbers). In particular, it is open whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $a^{2^n}+1$, $n\ge 1$, in particular if there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_problems)).

If $\gcd(b,p)=1$, we must have $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, because $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ iff $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ ([Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.E2.88.921_and_the_first_supplement)).